# Water turned off but toilet cistern still filling ready for next flush

Tags: water, leak

Can hear rushing water through pipes & my bill has gone up. Have turned off my main water tap by my front door which has stopped water to taps but the toilet is still able to flush & refill as normal?

Comment: Adding a question mark to a statement doesn't make it a question. What are you asking exactly? Either you haven't turned off your main water valve or there's more to your plumbing system than you realize.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What happens if, when the water is turned off, you turn on a faucet? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Apologies, asking if it's more likely to be a problem with the water mains tap rather than say a leak in a boiler. As you can tell I have no idea about plumbing, was hoping I might get some guidance of where the problem might lie if a cistern can fill but everything else seems to be shut off. J

Comment: You didn't drain the system. Toilet is the low point; that's where it will go. What's the actual problem? Trying to find why your bill is higher? Changing the toilet or its guts?